# Regex: Read between pre-defined tokens

Tags: .net, regex

I'm at a loss, I need some help.

The string looks like:

```
"Hello World

@start some text @end

@start more text @end"
```

I need a regex pattern which will match anything from `@start` to the first `@end`.  In this example, we would have two matches (`@start (some text) @end`).  The text inside of the @ tags could contain a newline character.

Any ideas?

Comment: @start{1}(.*\n)+@end{1}.  The problem is the (.*\n)+ part because it matches end.  That pattern returns one match (start some text end

start more text end)

Comment: Try the non-greedy version with `.*?` instead of `.*`. BTW, why do you need `{1}`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
string s = "Hello world\n@start text1 @end\n@start text2 @end";
Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<=@start)[\s\S]*?(?=@end)");
var mm = r.Matches(s);
```

produced 2 matches.

The tricks are:

- use non-greedy matching (`*?` instead of just `*`)
- use `[\s\S]` to match really *any* character, including newline
- use lookahead/lookbehind (`(?...)`)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: (got the *? backwards. fixing it.)

```
(?<=@start).*?(?=@end)
```

EDIT: Whoops, make that Singleline

"." will not match newlines by default, but you can enable this. How to do that depends on which regex engine you are using, but generally it's called "singleline"

EDIT: Saw that you are using .NET. Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RegexSandboxCSharp {
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

      string l_input = @"Hello World  

@start some text @end  

@start more text @end";


      // This is the relevant piece of code:    
      MatchCollection l_matches = Regex.Matches( l_input, "(?<=@start).*?(?=@end)", RegexOptions.Singleline );



      foreach ( Match l_match in l_matches ) {
        Console.WriteLine( l_match.Value );
      }

      Console.ReadKey( true );

    }
  }
}
```